# Interact with float between scripts error

Tags: c#

I want to import a float fromm a certain script to another :

the float form the script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ship : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float munitions = 0f;
}
```

so I did this in my other script :

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destructable : MonoBehaviour


{
    public Ship munitions;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) 
{
    if (!canBeDestroyed)
    {
        return;
    }
    Bullet bullet = collision.GetComponent<Bullet>();
    if (bullet != null)
    {
        if (!bullet.isEnemy)
        {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(bullet.gameObject);
        munitions += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

But I have the error :

Assets\Destructable.cs(48,13): error CS0019: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Ship' and 'int

And I don't know why...

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: If `Ship` declared `public float munitions; public float ballast;`, what would `munitions += 10;` (where `munitions` is of type `Ship`, as in `Desctrutable` above) mean?

Comment: what do you mean by "public float ballast" ???

Comment: Well if you had a second field in your `Ship` object. You'd be asking the compiler to be psychic re which field you wanted to change.

Comment: i don't understand at all sorry

Comment: You are calling `÷= 10` on this field: `public Ship munitions;`. It is of type `Ship`. What on Earth do you believe that += 10 to be doing?! What is the result of `instanceOfShip += 10` because I sure have no clue what that should mean.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that you can't add types `Ship` and `int` together.
What you can do to fix this is write:

```c
munitions.munitions += 10.0f;
```

What you were doing before is adding an integer value to your ship class instead of the float variable contained inside it. The code I provided earlier should fix that code.

Next time you try to access a variable from a class keep in mind that you have to use

```c
class.variable
```

since C# doesn't automatically know what variable you are trying to change.

Comment: Thank you!
I understood but now I have a new error, when the program is running. When this is happening :

    Bullet bullet = collision.GetComponent<Bullet>();
    if (bullet != null)
    {
        if (!bullet.isEnemy)
        {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(bullet.gameObject);
        munitions += 10;
        }
    }

I have this error : 

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Destructable.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Destructable.cs:46)

Without "munitions.munitions += 10;" its working

Comment: Since you're getting a NullReferenceException when the munitions class is being called upon in any way, you simply don't have the ``munitions`` variable set to anything. You can fix this by adding the Ship class to a gameobject and setting the variable to the new component. If you don't understand what I mean please checkout [this video by Tarodev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtv7mjj_iog)

Answer (score 1):

You trying to plus to variable with class Ship, but you need to plus to variable which inside "munitions" variable.

```
munitions.munitions += 10;
```

Also, if i were you i would renamed munitions to ship in this line

```
public Ship munitions;
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood but now I have a new error, when the program is running. When this is happening : `Bullet bullet = collision.GetComponent<Bullet>(); if (bullet != null) { if (!bullet.isEnemy) { Destroy(gameObject); Destroy(bullet.gameObject); munitions += 10; } }` I have this error : **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Destructable.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Destructable.cs:46)** Without `munitions.munitions += 10;` its working. Can you help me plz

Comment: it because you didn`t initialised this variable before, variable is null. You  can do it in constructor.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors